# Streaming large files (>2GB over IIS) using WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload very large files (>2GB) to my WebAPI application (Running on .NET 4.5.2, Windows 2012R2).

Setting the httpRuntime maxRequestLength property is of no use because it's only working with files smaller than 2GB.

I'm currently using a custom MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to read the entire stream on the Server and I've already turned off buffering using a custom WebHostBufferPolicySelector.

What I discovered is that ASP.NET (or WebAPI for that matter) uses a HttpBufferlessInputStream under the Hood which has a field called _disableMaxRequestLength. If I set this value to to true (via reflection), I can stream files of any size.

However, fiddling around these with these internas is clearly not a good way.

The HttpRequest class used for the request has a method called [GetBufferlessInputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195568(v=vs.110).aspx) which has an overload that allows to disable the maxRequestLength.

My question is: How can I get the WebAPI to use this overload instead of the Standard one?

Is there any way to replace the Default HttpRequest or HttpContext class? Or do I really Need to use reflection for the whole stuff?

This is the code I'm currently using to disable the maxRequestLength:

```
    private void DisableRequestLengthOnStream(HttpContent parent)
    {
        var streamContentProperty = parent.GetType().GetProperty("StreamContent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (streamContentProperty == null) return;
        var streamContent = streamContentProperty.GetValue(parent, null);
        if (streamContent == null) return;
        var contentProperty = typeof(StreamContent).GetField("content", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (contentProperty == null) return;
        var content = contentProperty.GetValue(streamContent);
        if (content == null) return;
        var requestLengthField = content.GetType().GetField("_disableMaxRequestLength", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (requestLengthField == null) return;
        requestLengthField.SetValue(content, true);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Very interesting question. Out of curiosity, have you considered just using FTP to do the transfer?

Comment: That is not possible in my Scenario...

Comment: By 'the standard one', do you mean using an InputString?

Comment: @JustinR.No. There are two GetBufferlessInputStream methods on the HttpRequest class. One takes a Parameter wich Switches the maxRequestCheck on/off, and the other one just Returns the HttpBufferlessInputStream with the Check turned on.

Comment: @Henning Krause Give this a read. http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found a pretty simple solution. The answer from @JustinR. would work, of course. But I wanted to continue to use a MultipartFormDataStreamProvider because that handles all the MIME stuff.

The solution is to simply create a new StreamContent instance with the correct bufferless Input stream and populate it with the headers from the original Content:

```
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);
var content = new StreamContent(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true));
foreach (var header in Request.Content.Headers)
{
    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
}

await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

Comment: Doesn't break the 2GB barrier...soooo

Comment: Thanks, works for me, I have uploaded a 21 megabyte xml file (in dev anyway).

Comment: The IIS has a limit at 2GB... no way around. I changed my implementation to perform chuncked uploads (jquery/blueimp)

Comment: You're better off that way anyway just for easier resume capability, imo.

Comment: @HenningKrause I know this is an old question but I'm trying to build a web api 2 endpoint that accepts chunked uploads (with jquery/blueimp) but only the first chunk is saved and the rest is never sent. Do you have an example how you fixed yours?

Comment: @HenningKrause Thx for sharing the code. Did you try Owin Selfhost instead of IIS?

Comment: Nope. Was never an option.

Comment: Hi, I'm using this approach but I got this error => "Error reading MIME multipart body part.System.Web.HttpException (0x800703E3): The client disconnected."

I extended this => <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="3000000" executionTimeout="300" /> but still the same

Is there anyone facing this issue as well?

Comment: I configured this as well <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />

Answer (score 2):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406798%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the way to read an unlimited stream length is `HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream`. You could do something like:

```
public void ReadStream(HttpContext context, string filePath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true)))
    using (var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096, true))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filestream))
    {
        var readBuffer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        writer.WriteAsync(readBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know its only an example, but that `var readBuffer = reader.ReadToEnd();` doesn't strike me as facilitating reading "unlimited stream length"; I've had problems with (single) large allocations, even with the memory available. :(

Comment: @MeirionHughes I absolutely agree. I have similar code that streams this progressively into the file. It also does so asynchronously. However, all of the additional code to do so distracts from the usage of the function, and I wanted to make the example clear.

Comment: With the above code I am getting below error  "The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream."

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no easy way to do that.

The call to `GetBufferlessInputStream` is buried deep inside `HttpControllerHandler`, which is the lowest possible layer of ASP.NET Web API (it's an HTTP Handler on top of which the entire Web API stack is built.

You can see [the code here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/HttpControllerHandler.cs#L309).

As you see it's full of statics, long methods with nested logical conditions, internals and privates,  so it's not really customisable at all.
While the entire `HttpControllerHandler` in Web API can theoretically be replaced with a custom implementation (this is done inside `HttpControllerRouteHandler` - by overriding the `GetHttpHandler` method), it's de facto impossible (you could try to internalize this code in your application, but you'll end up dragging lots of extra internal classes too).

The best thing (and I dread to say that) that comes to my mind is to modify the source `HttpControllerHandler` class to use the overload of `GetBufferlessInputStream` that disables the request length limit and recompile the `System.Web.Http.WebHost` assembly, and deploy that modded version with your app.