# IIS Express 8 - Max allowed length

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

In case the below is too long, my question is whether IIS Express 8 in Visual Studio 2013 obeys the `maxAllowedContentLength` attribute or if it has some overriding value that prevents large requests

---

When debugging some webapi calls against Visual Studio 2013, I'm receiving this error:

`Maximum request length exceeded.`

I searched the internet and everything seems to be pointing to these two config entries:

```
IIS 6-: maxRequestLength
IIS 7+: maxAllowedContentLength
```

I've added both these config entries to my web.config with a value of 4294967295, just to be safe.  When I try to make the call to the controller, I still receive the error.

This made me think that I was sending some gigantic amount of data to the server, but fiddler tells me this:

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      4,327,084      (headers:1,026; body:4,326,058)
Bytes Received:  3,808      (headers:434; body:3,374)
```

And seeing as how, 4,327,084 < 4,294,967,295 I feel like there shouldn't be any problems with this request.

The next place I thought of looking is my server code:

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
}

var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(@"C:\tmp", Int32.MaxValue);

var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        throw t.Exception;   // <== This gets thrown
```

So once again, the size of the request is significantly less than the buffer size for the data stream provider.

So in summary, I have no idea what's going on.  The request is fairly big, but from what I can tell, there's no reason this should be failing.  Is this caused by VS13/IIS Exp8?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

---

*Here's the config entry I said I would provide*

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
```

---

*And here's the full exception*

```
System.IO.IOException: Error reading MIME multipart body part. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.
   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.ValidateRequestEntityLength()
   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.GetPreloadedContent(Byte[] buffer, Int32& offset, Int32& count)
   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.IO.Stream.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__d(Stream stream, ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrim[TInstance,TArgs](TInstance thisRef, TArgs args, Func`5 beginMethod, Func`3 endMethod)
   at System.IO.Stream.BeginEndReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.SeekableBufferedRequestStream.<ReadAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<MultipartReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<MultipartReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<ReadAsMultipartAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BICWeb.webservices.controllers.FormsDesignerController.<Post>d__b.MoveNext() in c:\code\BIC_CORE\TRUNK\BIC\src\BICWeb\webservices\controllers\FormsDesignerController.cs:line 300
```

---

*And the inner exception*

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.
   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.ValidateRequestEntityLength()
   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.GetPreloadedContent(Byte[] buffer, Int32& offset, Int32& count)
   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.IO.Stream.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__d(Stream stream, ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrim[TInstance,TArgs](TInstance thisRef, TArgs args, Func`5 beginMethod, Func`3 endMethod)
   at System.IO.Stream.BeginEndReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.SeekableBufferedRequestStream.<ReadAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<MultipartReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Your numbers are so big that they might be considered invalid and ignored. Or, god forbid, overflow. Set them to 10M which is enough for this request. And make sure they are in bytes, who knows.

Comment: Just a tip, replace `throw t.Exception;` with `t.Wait()`. That handles the error better and doesn't destroy the stored stack. Probably, you shouldn't be using ContinueWith anyway and use await.

Comment: @usr Yeah, I was using await for a while, but I was in "change everything and see if anythign works" mode

Comment: @usr As for your first comment, .Net actually throws a config error if you overflow that entry.  From MSDN, the value I have entered is the max value allowed, and it should be working for that.

Comment: Actually, I forgot something important. Post the full exception ToString. This is usually the first thing I ask for, not sure why I forgot.

Comment: Exceeding `maxAllowedContentLength` would return a  404.13 status. Do you get that? That limit is a IIS limit, it seems to me, your problem is in your application. Maybe `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` has its own limitations.

Comment: @usr Sorry, Visual studio crashed twice on me.  I've posted both the exception and the inner exception

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I'm not getting that, but does webapi handle that behavior differently from the ASP.Net handler?  If not, it could totally be the MultipartFormDataStreamProvider, but the internet has yet to provide any limitations for that.

Comment: @mrK - `maxAllowedContentLength` has nothing to do with ASP.Net, it's an IIS thing. The exception is in System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream which is ASP.Net I don't remember whether there is a separate setting for that.

Comment: There is a `maxRequestLength` attribute on `system.web/httpRuntime`, default is 4096, you may want to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the code that throws:

```
private void ValidateRequestEntityLength()
{
    if (!this._disableMaxRequestLength && (this.Length > this._maxRequestLength))
    {
        if (!(this._context.WorkerRequest is IIS7WorkerRequest))
        {
            this._context.Response.CloseConnectionAfterError();
        }
        throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Max_request_length_exceeded"), null, 0xbbc);
    }
}
```

The ctor sets those options:

```
internal HttpBufferlessInputStream(HttpContext context, bool persistEntityBody, bool disableMaxRequestLength)
{
    this._context = context;
    this._persistEntityBody = persistEntityBody;
    this._disableMaxRequestLength = disableMaxRequestLength;
    HttpRuntimeSection httpRuntime = RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(this._context).HttpRuntime;
    this._maxRequestLength = httpRuntime.MaxRequestLengthBytes;
    this._fileThreshold = httpRuntime.RequestLengthDiskThresholdBytes;
    if (this._persistEntityBody)
    {
        this._rawContent = new HttpRawUploadedContent(this._fileThreshold, this._context.Request.ContentLength);
    }
    int contentLength = this._context.Request.ContentLength;
    this._remainingBytes = (contentLength > 0) ? contentLength : 0x7fffffff;
    this._length = contentLength;
}
```

And you can use this `HttpRequest` function to disable the limit:

```
public Stream GetBufferlessInputStream(bool disableMaxRequestLength)
{
    return this.GetInputStream(false, disableMaxRequestLength);
}
```

If you want to know how the byte limit is being computed, decompile `httpRuntime.MaxRequestLengthBytes`.

Comment: So this is all being done in a WebAPI controller, so Request is actually a HttpRequestMessage instead of a HttpRequest.  HttpRequestMessage doesn't seem to have a `GetBufferlessInputStream` method.

Comment: Actually, with a little help from this I was able to get it working.  Thanks for all the help!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753248/streaming-large-files-2gb-over-iis-using-webapi

Answer (score 0):

just a thought but from:
http://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1544/how-to-resolve-maximum-request-length-exceeded.aspx

"maxAllowedContentLength is measured in bytes while maxRequestLength is measured in kilobytes"

check they're both set correctly and try again

Comment: Either way, they should be set correctly.  I'll update my post with the actual config value