# ASP.NET WebAPI 2 "streaming" Service [HttpPost]

Tags: c#, json, stream, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following requirement:

The client will "stream" a very large JSON array to my WebAPI 2 Service. I know how to implement an `[HttpPost]` Method, wait until end of response and process JSON array.

But how can i receive such a stream and process it in parallel during streaming, object by object?

Comment: Have you looked at [Streaming large files (>2GB over IIS) using WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25753248) plus [How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43747477) and [Deserialize json array stream one item at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20374083)?  The actual streaming part isn't mult-threaded but you should be able to parallelize further processing of the objects after deserialization while streaming.

Comment: I am a little bit lost. I looked at your provided links but have no clue. Could someone maybe post a simple httppost webapi method? I am not expecting a full working solution, no! But it would be very helpful to see how it should look like generally ...

Comment: No one can help?